# How to take my app off in the iphone appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an App in iphone appstore, it have both Lite and Full editions. Lite one have ad and limited features.

What I want to do is that I want to make the Full edition free and supported with Ads, so the lite one has no reason to exist, then I want to remove it from appstore. Or is there any method to merge these two apps into one?  in that case my old users can all upgrade to the new full-featured all free app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to 'join them together'. You will have to alter the code of your FULL version to support ads, and change the price. The in iTunes Connect, you can just remove the lite version from the App Store.

Since your new app will be free, current users can then just download the free app. As long as you do not change the Bundle ID, any saved user information will stay in tact upon updating.

Comment: good explanation. @virsir: follow WrightsCS's answer and you'll be good

Comment: But how to remove the lite version from the AppStore, I did not find any link to do that.

Comment: Check out the iTunes Connect Developers Guide: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf,it explains how to remove an app. Basically, you need to remove it from sale, then you can delete it. Refer to page 93 in that guide.

Comment: @virsir: You might want to consider adding just one more update to the lite version that displays a message that explains it is obsolete and should be replaced with the now free full version.

Answer (score 6):

To remove your app from the App Store, you will have to uncheck all App Store territories under your **App Summary > Rights and Pricing**.
This will remove your app from sale.